# In Django, any way to create a model object without calling save other than bulk_create?

Tags: django

In Django, almost every method for creating a model object calls the `save` method of that model, including `create`, `get_or_create`, and `update_or_create`.

The only exception I'm aware of is `bulk_create`, which bypasses `save` to for database performance reasons.

My question: is there any other way a Django project could create a model object without hitting `save` other than via `bulk_create`?

Context: I'm modifying an existing Django project to do something on creation of any object (by checking `pk` in `save` of all models in a custom `model.Model` superclass) and want to make sure I'm not missing any object creation moments.